# Excel COM AddIn example in native C++

Tags: excel, visual-c++, add-in

I need to write an Excel AddIn to add user defined functions (UDF) to excel. I prefer to write it in unmanaged C++ (I already wrote one for Word). I am not able to locate an example from Internet.

What I want to know is that which interface I should look at and how the UDF functions are registered from COM AddIn. The documentation is quite unclear.

Comment: Did you find any C/C++ native example?